# knitr - two dataframes side-by-side with alternating row color in R-markdown

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, knitr

In R-markdown I like to show data frames with alternating row color (one grey one white) like this

```
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2), col_2 = c(2,4))
knitr::kable(df)%>%
  row_spec(seq(1,nrow(df),2), background="#D3D3D3") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width=F)
```

Now I would like to show two data frames side by side. I can accomplish it with

```
df_1 <- df
df_2 <- df
knitr::kable(list(df_1, df_2)) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width=F)
```

I would like to achieve alternating row colors as well, but with it does not work as previously with `row_spec`. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a section with two columns, and just calling kable twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_cols`

```
library(dplyr)
knitr::kable(bind_cols(df_1, df_2) %>% setNames(rep(names(df_1), 2))) %>%
 row_spec(seq(1,nrow(df_1),2), background="#D3D3D3") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width=F)
```

---

Or convert to `matrix` and `cbind` as `matrix` can have duplicate column names.  With `data.frame`, the `make.unique` will modify the duplicate column name by appending a suffix to it

```
knitr::kable(cbind(as.matrix(df_1), as.matrix(df_2))) %>%
 row_spec(seq(1, nrow(df), 2),  background="#D3D3D3")
 kable_styling(full_width=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess if data frames have different number of rows, then I can just make them the same by filling with empty cells.

Comment: @user1700890 you may use `rowr::cbind.fill(df_1, df_2, fill = NA)`

Comment: `Package ‘rowr’ was removed from the CRAN repository.`

Comment: @user1700890 but you could install from the CRAN repo archives

Comment: @user1700890 you could get the tar file from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rowr/)and install it with `local = TRUE` in `install.packages`

Comment: @user1700890 or if you don't have a package, then create a sequence column in each of the files, and do a join by that column